# How to add count to a eloquent array?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5

In my webshop i have searchgroups and searchtags.

Every searchtag belongs to a searchgroup.

The searchtags are connected to bikegroups with a many-to-many relation.

DB:
[image]

How i retrieve my groups with tags:

```
$searchgroups = SearchGroup::with('searchtags')->get();
```

Now i want to count how many times each searchtag exists in tags_bike_groups and display it.

[image]

So that i can display:

Year

2016 (2)

2017 (5)

2018 (0)

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I got it.

The solution is:

```
$searchgroups = SearchGroup::with('searchtags')->get();
    foreach($searchgroups as $searchgroup) {
        foreach($searchgroup->searchtags as $searchtag) {

            $searchtag->count = count(TagsBikeGroup::where('searchtags_id',$searchtag->id)->get());
        }
    }
```

Then in your view you can get the count like this:

```
{{ $searchtag->count }}
```

Comment: Give it a try: `SearchGroup::with('searchtags')->withCount('searchtags.tagsBikeGroups')->get();` (cannot test it right now). More in section [Counting Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$searchgroups = SearchGroup::with('searchtags')->get();
```